# Quadcopter that can carry heavy things?

Tags: quadcopter, raspberry-pi

So, while I was out drinking with a couple of my friends, one of us said something like 'man, wouldn't it be cool if the beer just came to us?' and that got me thinking.

We all have seen some crazy things people do with quadcopters (or polycopters even), but would it be possible (and not too expensive) to build a quadcopter that could carry, say, a crate of beer? (16-20kg)

I'm a bit of a tinkerer and I've built some minor things with rasp. pi's before but never tried myself at a quadcopter, because they are quite a big piece of work, but being able to fly a crate of beer right in front of me would be pretty awesome.

That aside, how strong would such a quadcopter have to be? In terms of motors, propellers, battery & frame. I'm a complete noob when it comes to RPM and the like, so I wouldn't even know where to begin. I have, of course, read through most of the available tutorials on the internet, but they don't answer my question of **what exactly to look for** when I want my quadcopter to be able to carry something specific.

Comment: Have you seen ["Heavy Lifting Copters: the beerlift"](http://hackaday.com/2013/09/20/heavy-lifting-copters-can-apparently-lift-people/) ?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Shtickler, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me put it this way. To carry anything, the total thrust generated by the quadcopter/multicopter's motors needs to be atleast twice the total weight you wish to carry. This includes the weight of the quadcopter itself as well.

The more heavier the copter, the lesser the kV of the motor must be, since you'll need large propellers ( I'm talking atleast 15 inches for your idea) so that the propellers are stable on the motor.

You cannot use frames currently on the market as I don't think they're strong enough to handle a large payload. You should try making your own frame, maybe 3d printing it or carving it out yourself. Materials you can use can be carbon fiber or even balsa wood, which is really light. You can look up frame designs on the web, but my suggestion is to go with an integrated prop guard design for your frame, since that'll be added protection without adding anything more to the frame.

You'll need lipos of large capacity in order to have a decent run time. Go look up Oscar Liang's website for understanding rpm, battery selection, motors and props, etc.